# What is the HealthCheck NodePort in kuberntes service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I created a Service of LoadBalancer Type in Kubernetes.
It was automatically assigned a HealthCheck NodePort.
I get the following response.

`{ "service": { "namespace": "ingress-nginx", "name": "ingress-nginx-controller" }, "localEndpoints": 1 }`

I'm curious how this operation is performed and responded to.

I thought maybe I was sending requests to liveness probe and readiness probe, but my liveness and readiness are only supposed to send an 'ok' response. So I think it's something else.
I'm wondering which component of kubernetes receives that response, does the actual healthcheck, and formats it into this json and passes it along.